# Naming of word combination

Tags: string, naming-conventions

Assuming "A B C D" to be a sentence, is there any dedicated name for two following string deconstructions :

1)

size:3 <=> {"ABC", "BCD"}

size:2 <=> {"AB","BC", "CD"}

2)

size:3 <=> {"ABC", "ABD", "BCD"}

size:2 <=> {"AB","AC", "AD", "BC", "BD", "CD"}

Please, note that we never permute elements...

Thank you in advance,

-Bast

Answer (score 0):

Like java code

```
String sequence = "A B C D";

public List createConventions(String sequence,int mode) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] elements = sequence.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < elements.length; j++) {
            if (mode == 1) {
                result.add(elements[i] + elements[j]);
            } else if (mode == 2) {
                for (int k = j + 1; k < elements.length; k++) {
                    result.add(elements[i] + elements[j] + elements[k]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm searching for a way to name the two different ways I presented... (BTW: if(mode==2){} else if(mode==2) {} seems wrong

Comment: Thanks. I did not test the code, because I already wrote my code which does this...Again I'm searching for a way to call this string decomposition/combination...